# How can I save data in json format through jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

Null data is transfer from html page through jquery please help me
**here is my api code asp.net core its working fine**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<LeaveSubmit>> Submitdata()
{
    try
    {
        LeaveSubmit lobj = new LeaveSubmit();
        //  string myobj = Convert.ToString(lobj);
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.FromObject(lobj);
        if (jsonObject == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jsonFile);
            var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(json);
            var experienceArrary = jsonObj.GetValue("Notes") as JArray;
            var newnotes = jsonObject;
            experienceArrary.Add(newnotes);
            jsonObj["Notes"] = experienceArrary;
            string newJsonResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(jsonFile, newJsonResult);

            //  var response = await newJsonResult;
            return Ok("Success");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.telemetryClient.TrackException(ex);
        return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**jquery code when i click on submit button is send to api is null so null data is saved in json page**
//Data Save.//`$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
datapass();
});

```
    function datapass() {
        var values = {};

        var values = $("#notesval").val();

        var myvalue = JSON.stringify(values);

        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.origin + "/api/ServiceApi/Submitdata",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: myvalue,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function () {

                //console.log("Savesuccessful");
                //console.log(data);
                alert("Record Save Succesfully");

                //$(".loader").hide();
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error is occured");
                //console.log("My errror values:", error);

            }
        });
    }
   // Date save close.//`
```

Comment: could you display the content of  `$("#notesval").val()` ?

Comment: i want to save the content $("#notesval").val()

Comment: its an object? because you stringify after ? are you sure myvalue is json format?

Comment: you need to do two things: 1 in the javascript you should create your object like this values =  { MyProperty: $("#notesval").val() }; then you stringify it.  2 In your controller/action you need a parameter Submitdata([FromBody] MyClass myParam) and MyClass should have a property named MyProperty.  Basically your parameter needs to match the object you send as json from your ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform 3 steps:

**1.** Your C# code should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<LeaveSubmit>> Submitdata([FromBody] MyClass myModel)
{
    try
    {
        LeaveSubmit lobj = new LeaveSubmit();
        //  string myobj = Convert.ToString(lobj);
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.FromObject(lobj);
        if (jsonObject == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jsonFile);
            var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(json);
            var experienceArrary = jsonObj.GetValue("Notes") as JArray;
            var newnotes = jsonObject;
            experienceArrary.Add(newnotes);
            jsonObj["Notes"] = experienceArrary;
            string newJsonResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(jsonFile, newJsonResult);

            //  var response = await newJsonResult;
            return Ok("Success");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.telemetryClient.TrackException(ex);
        return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Basically add a parameter to hold the input.

**2.** You need to add a class that represents the input like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
      public string MyProperty {get; set;}
}
```

**3.** Your ajax call should look like this:

```
function datapass() {
        var values = { MyProperty:$("#notesval").val() };               

        var myvalue = JSON.stringify(values);

        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.origin + "/api/ServiceApi/Submitdata",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: myvalue,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function () {

                //console.log("Savesuccessful");
                //console.log(data);
                alert("Record Save Succesfully");

                //$(".loader").hide();
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error is occured");
                //console.log("My errror values:", error);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you clarification. its working. once again thank you so much

Comment: @samopps I glad it works now.  Can you please mark as the answer if it solved your problem.  Thank you.

Comment: but one things its call error function. success function can not be hit. if I clicked button so blank data also saved

Comment: @samopps validation is a different issue altogether. for that you will need to research data anotations and jquery validation unobstrusive